# Use VBA to change the internal margin and/or number format of a PowerPoint table cell

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a VBA loop that cycles through the selected cells of a PowerPoint table to update the formatting.  The following lines work great:

```
        With objTable.Rows(the_row).Cells(the_col).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font
            .Size = 12
            .Color = RGB(0, 0, 102)
        End With
        With objTable.Rows(the_row).Cells(the_col).Shape.TextFrame
            .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        End With
```

I'm having trouble finding the syntax to modify the number format (to change the number of decimals, add a comma, etc.) and to change the internal margin of the cell (which I can do manually with a right click -> Format Shape -> Text Box -> Internal Margin).  Usually I use the record macro option to get to that detailed syntax, but I'm not seeing that option in PowerPoint.

Comment: There is no longer a Record Macro option in PPT, unfortunately. You'll also discover (as I did) that there are far fewer resources available to the aspiring VBA developer who wants to work in PPT. MSDN documentation, and StackOverflow will be your best friend :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
With objTable.Rows(the_row).Cells(the_col).Shape.TextFrame

'Internal margin:
        .MarginLeft = 'value goes here
        .MarginRight = 'value goes here
        .MarginTop = 'value goes here
        .MarginBottom= 'value goes here


'number Format:

    .TextRange.text = Format(1000, "#,##0.00") 'replace 1000 with your value

end with
```

Comment: I had tried this and it didn't work, but it just hit me that the value probably has to be in pixels and not inches...is that right?  And for the number format, the number is already there, so would this work:  .TextRange.Text = Format(.TextRange.Text, "#,##0.00")?  Thanks!

Comment: I just tested both of those things, and they both work (use pixels and send the text range value as a parameter of the Format function).  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Values are POINTS, not pixels

Comment: Use VBA function [InchesToPoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172330%28v=office.11%29.aspx)